# working with NA values in R

Tags: r, na

```
NA | TRUE #output :TRUE 
FALSE & NA #output :FALSE
```

Can anyone explain how R is interpreting these statements and giving output.

Comment: R follows the mathematical logic: in the place of `NA` could be any other value to get the same result.

Comment: Yes, the question is the same one. Thanks @Henrik

Answer (score 5):

`NA | TRUE` returns `TRUE` because of the `|` , i.e., the OR-operator which returns true when at least one condition is satisfied.

Likewise, `NA | FALSE` would return `NA` because it can not be determined.

On the other hand, with the `&` AND-operator, the cases are reversed. Also, this is mathematical logic and not specific to the R-language.